# "nullptr" after initializing class by assignment in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I built a class which stores a buffer type, its size, and a pointer to that buffer.
The intention is to access the buffer through that pointer to perform all the operations.
The issue is, when I assign an instance of this class to another like so:

```cpp
    buffer = ExampleUsage(10);
```

the pointer breaks.

Here are the two classes (buffer and a usage for that buffer):
First the buffer I use in my example:

```cpp
    class ExampleBuffer {
    public:
        ExampleBuffer() :size(0), buffer(0) {}
        ExampleBuffer(size_t size) {
            this->size = size;
            buffer = vector<int>(size);
        }

        void Draw(int index, int val) {
            buffer[index] = val;
        }

        int Get(int index) {
            return buffer[index];
        }
    protected:
        int size;
        vector<int> buffer;
    };
```

Next the class I use to access the buffer and perform operations on it:

```cpp
    class ExampleUsage {
    public:
        ExampleUsage() :
            size(0),
            buffer(0), 
            ptr(&buffer) {}

        ExampleUsage(int size) :
            size(size),
            buffer(size), 
            ptr(&buffer) {}

        void Draw(int index, int val) {
            ptr->Draw(index, val);
        }

        int Get(int index) {
            return ptr->Get(index);
        }
    protected:
        int size;
        ExampleBuffer buffer;
        ExampleBuffer* ptr;
    };
```

Here's a program to demonstrate the problem.

```cpp
class SomeClass {
public:
    void Init() {
        buffer = ExampleUsage(10);
    }

    void DoStuff() {
        buffer.Draw(0, 1234);
    }

protected:
    ExampleUsage buffer;
};

int main() {
    SomeClass example;
    example.Init();
    example.DoStuff();
}
```

When it executes, it initializes `ExampleUsage` with its default constructor
and then another instance is generated in the `Init()` method of `SomeClass` and assigned to `buffer`.
Then the method `DoStuff()` is called, which executes the buffer's `Draw()` method and from there, the pointer should access the stored `ExampleBuffer` but it points to a nullptr instead leading to an exception.

I know that if I remove the line:

```cpp
    buffer = ExampleUsage(10);
```

and instead replace it with something like:

```cpp
    buffer.Init(10); //hypothetical method to initialize the class.
```

it will work.

Why does the pointer in `ExampleUsage` not point to the `ExampleBuffer` in this program?

Comment: Why are you going out of your way to make it work in such an odd way? People expect things to work with `new` or, in less common cases, factory methods, but calling something named `Init` is wildly out of place in most C++ code bases.

Comment: See this question about the [Rule of Three/Fiive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11).  You should implement (and use) a constructor for `SomeClass`, along with copy assignment, copy constructor, move assignment, and move constructors.

Comment: If you mean, the `Init` in `SomeClass`, it's just to demonstrate that the constructor wasn't used at that point. The init to replace the assignment at the end was to show a hypothetical way of how the error wouldn't occur. Neither of those were used in the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code you are copying both the vector and the pointer:

```
buffer = ExampleUsage(10);
```

At the end of the day the buffer object has a valid copy of the vector plus the pointer to some memory where another vector was located recently.

```
class ExampleUsage {
    // ...
    ExampleBuffer buffer; // This is a valid copy of the object
    ExampleBuffer* ptr; // Where does this ptr point after the copying?
};
```

This is the reason to get an exception.
Other questions regarding the code:
Why do you store the size externally if you have this information as vector::size()?
Why do you store both the vector and the pointer (preferring to use the pointer)?

Consider a simpler C++-idiomatic solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that cleared it up for me. In the implementation it is a vector with width and height, so there would be a width and a height variable, leaving the size in, was an oversight.